# How to use jsonb_set in jpa repository, for passing dynamic strings?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jsonb

postgres command works in pgadmin4 but not in java code

```
    String toAdd = "case_data->'business' || '{\"l\":\"cpaz\"}'";
this.orchestrateRepo.updateColumn(toAdd, case_id);



 @Query(value = "Update onboarding.onboarding_cases set case_data = jsonb_set(case_data, '{business}', ?1 )where case_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
        void updateColumn(String toAdd, BigInteger case_id);
```

I am passing a string toAdd,i want to insert the value dynamically..but it gives error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

the query works fine if i write it like this

```
 @Query(value = "Update onboarding.onboarding_cases set case_data = jsonb_set(case_data, '{business}', case_data->'business' || '{"t":"cpaz"}' )where case_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
        void updateColumn(BigInteger case_id);
```

What should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this issue. Posting an answer for those looking.

Only passing key value.

```
String toAdd = "value";
```

Changed the query to:

```
@Query(value = "Update onboarding.onboarding_cases set case_data=jsonb_set(case_data,'{business,key)}',to_jsonb(?1)) where case_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateColumn(String toAdd, BigInteger case_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add cast in `'{business,key)} AS TEXT[]'`

Example

```
@Query(value = "Update onboarding.onboarding_cases set case_data=jsonb_set(case_data,CAST('{business,key)}' AS TEXT[]),to_jsonb(?1)) where case_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
void updateColumn(String toAdd, BigInteger case_id);
```